# actionForTypeText Not Always Accurate In EarlGrey

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, earlgrey

Part of the EarlGrey test I'm writing includes saving a user's name. Here's the line of code:

`[[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"textField")] atIndex:0] performAction:[GREYActions actionForTypeText:name]]`

`name` is saved to `@"Thisisa UItest"`. Sometimes, the typed text is inaccurate: There are random letter capitalizations (I've put in a `.lowercase` check as a work-around), as well as letters omitted sometimes. For example, `"Thisisa itest"` would be typed. It's not consistent, but often enough to make the tests unreliable.

In `setUp`, I have this argument that I read would make typing slower:
`[[GREYUIThreadExecutor sharedInstance] drainUntilIdle];`

Let me know!

Edit: As per @Gautam 's request - 
XCode 8.2.1, iPad Pro, 9.7 inch simulator

Comment: This appears like a bug, but can you please share info on your environment as well? The iOS version, simuator/device model etc.

Comment: Running iPad Pro 9.7 simulator, on XCode 8.2.1

Comment: Sorry, can you please mention iOS version the iPad Pro is running as well?

Comment: Ariel, scratch that, we have been able to repro this and  I can confirm that this is an actual bug in the framework, I have created https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/issues/424, please follow on there.